# How to return the right HTTP status code from azure documentdb stored procedure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If I throw an error in azure DocumentDB stored procedure, it is returned as Bad Request to the client application. How to set the status code if the document is not found or if the user is not authorized to view a particular document?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783364.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures do not convert `Error.number` to response status code.  To communicate error code back to the client, sproc can make it part of the response, something like this: `__.response.setBody({ errorCode: err.number})`.

Comment: It would be great if documentDB provided option to throw an error like throw new Error(403, 'You are not authorized to view the document');